# how do i convert a 256bit integer from the boost multiprecision library to a string

Tags: c++, boost-multiprecision

How would I convert a boost::multiprecision::int256_t type variable into a string for example

```
string string1 = "12345";
boost::multiprecision::int256_t int1 (string1);
boost::multiprecision::int256_t int2 = int1 + 5
string string2;
// how do i make string2 equivalent to int2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just use the `str()` method on the multiprecision number.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/qq6v7qesh)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <string>

#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int main()
{    
    std::string string1 = "12345";
    boost::multiprecision::int256_t int1 (string1);
    boost::multiprecision::int256_t int2 = int1 + 5;
    std::string string2{ int2.str() };
    std::cout << string2 << "\n";
}

// Outputs:
//
//   12350
```